# Thévenin equivalent of circuit with two voltage sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, thevenin

I'm trying to figure out the Thévenin equivalent of the circuit shown in the circuit diagram below. The circuit is from a book on electronic circuits.

It would be great if somebody can show how to derive the Thévenin equivalent of the circuit as seen by node Vo in terms of V1, V2, R1, R2, and R3.

[image]

Thévenin resistance as seen by RL is (R3 + R1 || R2).

Comment: ok, you have the resistance, so what is the unloaded voltage?

Comment: Voltage at junction of R1 and R2 is V = -V2 +(((V1 +V2)/(R1 + R2) ) *R2) if RL is removed.  Is there another way?

Comment: @AmitM Disconnect R3 from R1 and R2. The current between the two voltage sources is then 500 uA. 500 uA times 10 k = 5. So the junction between R1 and R2 would either be 5 V less than 5 V, or else it would be 5 V more than -5 V. Either way, you get the same answer: 0 V. Not so? And if you now hook R3 back up to that? What then?

Comment: Periblepsis, voltage at the junction of R1 and R2 is zero.. I was checking the equation for voltage at node V at the junction of R1 and R2.

Comment: @AmitM If we agree, then this means the Thevenin voltage is 0V. The Thevenin resistance would be 5k (half of 10k). That is in series with R3. Yes?

Comment: @AmitM It simplifies [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzcdc.png).

Comment: Periblepsis, I agree with your answer. If V1 and V2 were not equal, would you agree with the calculation for V above?

Comment: @AmitM If not equal then `Vth=(V1*R2+V2*R1)/(R1+R2)` and `Rth=R1 || R2`.

Comment: periblepsis, it seems that your calculation omitted something. I believe that Vth = -V2 +(((V1 +V2)/(R1 + R2) ) *R2). Here V1=V2 = +5v. Please notice the polarity of the voltage sources wrt ground which is why there is -V2 in the equation for Vth. If I put in values of V1= V2 =+5, R1 =R2 = 10k , I get 0V for Vth which is correct.  The exact method is also shown by Simon Fitch. He seems to take the polarity of voltage sources later in the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

\$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ form a simple resistor potential divider, which is trivial to describe algebraically, but we need to be really careful with \$V_2\$, because even though \$V_2=+5V\$, the *absolute potential* ("absolute" meaning "with respect to ground") at the bottom of \$R_2\$ is actually \$-V_2=-5V\$. It can be a bit confusing when you have the *positive* side of a positive voltage source connected to ground. Just keep that in mind.

By contrast, the *potential* at the top of \$R_1\$ is unambiguous; it's clearly +5V relative to ground, or \$+V_1\$.

It's probably better if I redraw the situation with node names, and start using absolute potentials (with respect to ground):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6DSxj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We are interested in the potential \$V_X\$ at node X, the junction of the pair of resistors. That will be the Thevenin voltage, since we leave the output open, disregarding load \$R_L\$. Consequently there's no current through \$R_3\$, and the open circuit output voltage \$V_O\$ will be the same  as \$V_X\$

We already have

$$ V_A = 0V + V_1 = +5V $$
$$ V_B = 0V - V_2 = -5V $$

If we treat this using Ohm's law, to find the current \$I\$ through \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, it would go as follows. Find the potential difference across the pair, and divide by the total resistance of the pair:

$$ I = \frac{V_A - V_B}{R_1 + R_2} $$

Then you apply Ohm's law again to work out the voltages \$V_{R1}\$ and \$V_{R2}\$ across each resistor:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= I R_1 \\ \\
&= R_1 \frac{V_A - V_B}{R_1+R_2}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R2} &= I R_2 \\ \\
&= R_2 \frac{V_A - V_B}{R_1+R_2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now you must find the potential at the junction of the resistors, node X. This is an application of KVL. Start at some point where you *know* the potential (either at the top of the chain or the bottom), and jump over elements along the path towards the node of interest, summing the changes in potential across each element as you go.

If you started at the top, node A, you would be subtracting voltages across the resistors as you go, because according to my annotated direction of \$I\$, the lower end of all the resistors in the chain must be lower in potential than the upper end. Therefore each time we jump downwards across a resistor, this must incur a *fall* in potential.

I want to do this starting at B, though, going upwards. We want to know the potential \$V_X\$ at node X, so starting at node B, where absolute potential is \$V_B\$, work your way up the chain adding each potential change as you go. Here there's only one jump, across \$R_2\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_X &= V_B + V_{R_2} \\ \\
&= V_B + R_2 \frac{V_A - V_B}{R_1+R_2} \\ \\
&= V_B + (V_A - V_B) \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}
\end{aligned}
$$

You could apply this procedure for any number of resistors in the chain. KVL will always work out.

<sub>Note: If you continued the journey to node A, your "accumulated" potential must necessarily equal \$V_A\$. The sum of voltages across all resistors in the chain *must* equal the potential difference between the two ends. That's just another way of stating KVL.</sub>

That's all. There's nothing left to do except to plug in the numbers:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_X &= (-5V) + \left[(+5V) - (-5V)\right] \frac{10k\Omega}{10k\Omega+10k\Omega} \\ \\
&= (-5V) + (+10V)\frac{1}{2} \\ \\
&= 0V
\end{aligned}
$$

This was an obvious result from the start, since the two resistors are equal, meaning that their junction would have a potential exactly half-way between the two ends at −5V and +5V.

\$V_X = 0V\$ is the Thevenin voltage, so the Thevenin equivalent is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbDTK8.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The junction of R1 and R2 is loaded by a resistance comprising R3 in series with RL. This **effective** load connects to ground. If we removed the load, the voltage at the junction of R1 and R2 is zero volts because the two voltage sources (V1 and V2) are equal in magnitude but opposite in polarity.

Given that the **effective** load can only ground this node, the current that flows must be zero amps.

Hence, the Thevenin output voltage is zero. For the Thevenin output impedance, replace the voltage sources with shorts and use what you know about resistor networks to calculate the impedance.

Comment: V1 and V2 have opposite polarity so they cant be treated as a single voltage source?

Comment: ...so what is the voltage at the junction between R1 and R2?

Comment: Thevenin resistance as seen by RL is ( R3 + R1 || R2 )

Comment: @AmitM you are quite correct and I will delete my answer while I fix it.

Comment: **FIXED** and sorry about my initial error.

Comment: Andy_aka please check the question's comments and see if they are correct.

Comment: @AmitM I am unsure what it is that you want me to check.

Comment: Voltage V at the junction of R1 and R2.

Comment: It's zero volts (as explained in my repaired answer) @AmitM

Comment: Andya_aka, If R1 and R2 were not equal then it would have been non zero as in the calculation for V.

Comment: @AmitM correct, but they are equal value.